# DataGrid Tabbing goes from cell to content

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid consisting primarily of TemplateColumns. I am having the issue where when tabbing through the row, it appears to go to the cell, then the content within the cell (ie a textbox or togglebutton). The ideal situation is that tabbing through the columns puts the focus on the content and skips the cell. I may be interpreting what is happening incorrectly, but visually it appears to be the case. I have tried:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Group Value"
                                    MinWidth="30"
                                    Width=".02*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                                Value="False" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeBinding, 
                                                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 IsReadOnly="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                               AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
                                               Path=DataContext.IsReadOnly}"
                                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But that doesn't work as I assumed it would. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it does seem to focus the `DataGridTemplateColumn` before it focuses on the control within it while tabbing.

In my search for a solution, I came across this:
http://iyalovoi.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/wpf-datagrid-tabbing-from-cell-to-cell-does-not-set-focus-on-control/

You can attach the `FocusAttacher` to the control within the template column, and it will steal the focus from it.  It worked great for me.

Comment: This doesn't allow focus to leave the control by pressing Tab.

Answer (score 3):

I tried many things which I found in different blog, but those did not work.
But then I found one simple and effective technique which worked like champ!!!

This need only 2 steps.

**1. Add Style in your resource file:**

```
<!-- Cell Editing For DataGrid-->
<Style x:Key="CellEditingStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
</Style>
```

**2. Add this style in your data Grid:**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{DynamicResource grdLoadsPerMonths}"
                        CellStyle="{StaticResource CellEditingStyle}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LoadsPerMonth, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

That is it. This has solved all the problem. No more work, no more class needs to be added.

Comment: This makes the problem even worse. Before it took 2 tabs to bring focus to the control inside of the DataGridTemplateColumn, now tab completely skips over it entirely, making it impossible to use the control without using the mouse..

Comment: This solution works well. Just to catch the the tab going into Textbox, add KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True" to TextBox.